# localhost:8080 this site can't be reached

Tags: mysql, xampp, localhost

I have xampp installed on my windows 8.1 32-bit. apache and MySQL are running. and i am having kind of weird problem. after a restart of my machine localhost runs but only and if tried reloading it won't load. so i tried some solutions over the internet, include clearing my cache. so i tried clearing my cache, localhost loaded but again only for one time, tried reloading it, but won't load . here is the error log for the day

```
    [Thu Jul 07 01:09:02.134872 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 8272:tid 1776] [client 100.93.115.237:57084] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/
    [Thu Jul 07 12:27:38.232732 2016] [core:warn] [pid 5548:tid 392] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
    [Thu Jul 07 12:27:38.772405 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5548:tid 392] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
    [Thu Jul 07 12:27:42.577513 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5548:tid 392] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Thu Jul 07 12:27:42.577513 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5548:tid 392] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
    [Thu Jul 07 12:27:42.577513 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5548:tid 392] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
    [Thu Jul 07 12:27:42.624392 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5548:tid 392] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1128
    [Thu Jul 07 12:27:44.139436 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1128:tid 356] AH01873: Init:  Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
    [Thu Jul 07 12:27:44.266630 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1128:tid 356] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
    [Thu Jul 07 12:30:38.084960 2016] [core:warn] [pid 6960:tid 376] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
    [Thu Jul 07 12:30:38.412969 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 6960:tid 376] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
    [Thu Jul 07 12:30:38.472973 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6960:tid 376] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Thu Jul 07 12:30:38.472973 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6960:tid 376] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
    [Thu Jul 07 12:30:38.472973 2016] [core:notice] [pid 6960:tid 376] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
    [Thu Jul 07 12:30:39.464998 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6960:tid 376] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5448
    [Thu Jul 07 12:30:40.893037 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5448:tid 348] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
    [Thu Jul 07 12:30:40.957041 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5448:tid 348] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
    [Thu Jul 07 13:16:55.613227 2016] [core:warn] [pid 5772:tid 392] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
    [Thu Jul 07 13:16:55.910117 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5772:tid 392] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
    [Thu Jul 07 13:16:56.925786 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5772:tid 392] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Thu Jul 07 13:16:56.925786 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5772:tid 392] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
    [Thu Jul 07 13:16:56.925786 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5772:tid 392] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
    [Thu Jul 07 13:16:57.082044 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5772:tid 392] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5560
    [Thu Jul 07 13:16:58.566490 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5560:tid 396] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
    [Thu Jul 07 13:16:58.707150 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5560:tid 396] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: `Init: Session Cache is not configured` looks like you have made a mistake in your SSL config. What happens if you remove your SSL Config.

Comment: as i was having blocked port and missing dependencies problem before, i changed port from 443 to 4433, so now i had no blocked problem, tried changing it back to 443, blocked port problem returned and now even if i change port back to 4433 the port remains blocked .